# Select with image using Jquery Mobile 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, combobox

i was trying to make a combobox with images using Jquery Mobile. I got a way here: [jQuery Mobile Thumbnail list in a Select Drop Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289188/jquery-mobile-thumbnail-list-in-a-select-drop-down)

```
JsFiddle here:     http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ba4gG/4/
```

But when i use it in my project(working with Jquery Mobile 1.4.2), it doesn't work. I think it's because it was written for another previous version(1.2 i think). Could anyone tell me what changes i must do to make it work in the current version?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just for people who could have the same problem. The problem was no the version, the problem was i put the function in the onDeviceReady, but it must be on a event called: pagecreate in the document definition.

Thank you for your help